# Anything equivalent to Android-Scanner-Compat-Library for iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, nrf52, nrf51

Looking for BLE scanner similar to  Android-Scanner-Compat-Library  for iOS  ?
Using scanForPeripheralsWithServices but some time BLE peripheral (device ) not found in the scan.

Comment: A simple google search got me this: https://www.netguru.com/blog/5-best-ios-ble-frameworks-comparison. How similar do you want it to be?

Comment: Remember you won't find legacy bluetooth devices on iOS, only BLE devices

Comment: Any library would use `scanForPeripherals`, so it would not solve the problem. Add the code and detailed description of possible problem.